# Flutter bloc - Casting issue

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have an issue when trying to update a bloc's state locally. I am trying to retrieve the state to manipulate the data and then emit a new state so it reflects those changes in the UI. I am not trying to manipulate the state itself just the property.
The property is of type List this class is defined like this

This entity is in the domain layer. I have another class at the data layer which is defined like this

I am trying to modify one user's email and name but when retrieving the property is being parsed to List which is not correct since my porperty is defined as a List and when trying to update the list it fails. I do not want to cast the entire list to a userDataModel since that layer(presentation) where the bloc is should not know about models just entities.

I have tried to specified the types in both classes but I still get the same error.
I have tried to copyWith the class and still having the same result.
I have tried casting the list from List to List but does take effect.

Here is the error I am getting in the console.

Maybe I am doing things wrong, I have never had to modified a state locally like this. Any advice with an example would be really helpful on how to handle this scenario.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please post the code realted to your bloc, i don't see anything wrong in above code

Comment: Already edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a good night sleep I found that this is the best way to update a bloc.

```
//!Modify user in users list
final UsersListLoaded actualState = state as UsersListLoaded;
List<UserData> modifiedList = actualState.usersList.map((userData) {
  return userData.id == event.user.id ? event.user : userData;
}).toList();
```

And afterwards emit the loaded state with proper data.